# How to use a variable outside the function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, return

My function:

```
function raspislinks($url)
{
    $chs = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt'); //Подставляем куки раз 
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36 OPR/29.0.1795.60");
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // не проверять SSL сертификат
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // не проверять Host SSL сертификата
    curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt'); //Подставляем куки два
    $htmll = curl_exec($chs);
    $pos   = strpos($htmll, '<strong><em><font color="green"> <h1>');
    $htmll = substr($htmll, $pos);
    $pos   = strpos($htmll, '<!--                </main>-->');
    $htmll = substr($htmll, 0, $pos);
    $htmll = end(explode('<strong><em><font color="green"> <h1>', $htmll));
    $htmll = str_replace('<a href ="', '<a href ="https://nfbgu.ru/timetable/fulltime/', $htmll);
    $GLOBALS['urls'];
    preg_match_all("/<[Aa][ \r\n\t]{1}[^>]*[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff][^=]*=[ '\"\n\r\t]*([^ \"'>\r\n\t#]+)[^>]*>/", $htmll, $urls);
    curl_close($chs);
}
```

How can I use a variable $urls outside the function? It is array. 
"return $urls"not working or am I doing something wrong. Help me please.

Comment: `return $urls` should work. Post the full code that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you load a value into `$GLOBALS['urls'];` in the function, you can then use `$urls` in code outside this function.

The `$GLOBALS` array holds one occurance for each of the variables available in the global scope, so once `$GLOBALS['urls'];` is set a value that value can also be referenced as `$urls`

Like

```
function raspislinks($url) {

 ...

    //$GLOBALS['urls'];
    preg_match_all("/<[Aa][ \r\n\t]{1}[^>]*[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff][^=]*=[ '\"\n\r\t]*([^ \"'>\r\n\t#]+)[^>]*>/",
                      $htmll, 
                      $GLOBALS['urls']
                   );

}

raspislinks('google.com');
foreach ( $urls as $url) {

}
```

A simpler way would be to put the data in a simple varibale and return it from the function

```
function raspislinks($url) {

 ...

    //$GLOBALS['urls'];
    preg_match_all("/<[Aa][ \r\n\t]{1}[^>]*[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff][^=]*=[ '\"\n\r\t]*([^ \"'>\r\n\t#]+)[^>]*>/",
                      $htmll, 
                      $t
                   );
    return $t;
}

$urls = raspislinks('google.com');
foreach ( $urls as $url) {

}
```